# WordPress plugin and JSON is not a valid response error

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm developing a simple plugin that checks if a user clicks on a button and sets a cookie in WordPress. Everything works fine, but when I try to update a post or a page, I get the "Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response." I cannot figure out how I can solve that. Also, I ask if I'm doing the right process to hook the translation and show the dialog at Worpress init.

```
if(!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

// ACTION
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cp_scripts');

function cp_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style('cookie-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('cookie-script', plugins_url('script.js', __FILE__));
}   

add_action('init', 'my_plugin_show_confirm');
// add_action('init', 'register_pll_translation');
 
function register_pll_translation() {
    if(function_exists('pll_register_string')) {
        pll_register_string( 'cp_form_subtitle', "string", 'cp-form', false );
        pll_register_string( 'cp_form_age_ok', "string", 'cp-form', false );
    }
}

function my_plugin_show_confirm() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cp_enter']) && !is_admin() )  {
    $current_url = get_the_permalink();

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        setcookie('cp_enter', 1 , time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        return;
    } ?>
   
    <div id="my-plugin-confirm">
        <form action="<?php echo $current_url ?>" method="post">
             <h2><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo('name'));?></h2>
             <p><Click to enter</p>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Enter</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a new function `my_plugin_set_cookie()`, that is hooked to init. This function checks if the form has been submitted and sets the cookie. After setting the cookie, it redirects the user to the same page to avoid resending the form if the user refreshes it. The `my_plugin_show_confirm()` function is now only responsible for outputting the form.

```
add_action('init', 'my_plugin_set_cookie');
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_plugin_show_confirm');

function my_plugin_set_cookie() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cp_enter']) && !is_admin() && isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        setcookie('cp_enter', 1 , time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN);
        wp_redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); // Redirect to the same page to avoid resending the form on refresh
        exit;
    }
}

function my_plugin_show_confirm() {
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['cp_enter']) && !is_admin() )  {
        $current_url = get_the_permalink(); ?>

        <div id="my-plugin-confirm">
            <form action="<?php echo $current_url ?>" method="post">
                <h2><?php echo esc_html(get_bloginfo('name'));?></h2>
                <p>Click to enter</p>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Enter</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    <?php }
}
```